# Use *ngFor object variable to display custom HTML Element

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an interface:

```
export interface Project {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    previewHTMLElement: string;
}
```

That I use in a list:

```
export const PROJECTLIST: Project[] = [
    {id: 1, name: 'a-cool-name', description: 'a cute description', previewHTMLElement: '<img src="assets/images/{{project.name}}.png">'}
]
```

That I am trying to use in an ngFor directive:

```
<div *ngFor="let project of projectList">
    {{project.previewHTMLElement}}
</div>
```

But this is just replacing `{{project.previewHTMLElement}}` with a #Text block that repeats whatever was in the string. I need to be able to put any kind of Element in the string and have it be rendered in as an actual HTMLElement.

What is the proper way to use angular directives to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 2):

Angular 2+ supports an `[innerHTML]` property binding that will render HTML. If you were to otherwise use interpolation, it would be treated as a string.

I wouldn't trust anything to be used with innerHTML without cleaning it first. So, with DomSanitizer, a service of Angular helps to prevent attackers from injecting malicious client-side scripts into web pages, which is often referred to as Cross-site Scripting or XSS.

```html
<div *ngFor="let project of projectList">
  <span [innerHTML]="project.previewHTMLElement | sanitizeHtml"></span>
</div>
```

The sanitizer pipe

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeHtml } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Pipe({ name: 'sanitizeHtml' })
export class sanitizeHtmlPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private _sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  public transform(value: any): SafeHtml {
    const sanitizedContent = this._sanitizer.sanitize(1, value);
    return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(sanitizedContent);
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pqwwes?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: I understand what you mean with avoiding XSS and how that means I would need to sanitize my input, but it was my understanding that Angular does that automatically? Given the following from your example:

    ` [innerHTML]="project.previewHTMLElement | sanitizeHtml" `

I don't understand the Sanitizer itself in that it calls

    ` return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(value); `

Does this not tell the sanitizer to bypass security anyway?

Comment: Good catch! We should sanitize it first. `const sanitizedContent = this._sanitizer.sanitize(1, value); return this._sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(sanitizedContent);` I have edited the answer.

Comment: I see, thank you for the clarification, I will give this a shot and see what happens! I was reading that HTML sanitizing is something that can be controlled via a whitelist or blacklist of tags for example. I was googling and struggling to find an answer for how exactly angular sanitizes content. Is this something I need to look in to so as to better understand what I can and can't put inside project.previewHTMLElement?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this, some more interesting/recomended than others.

What you are trying wouldn't work, because interpolation will print stuff as a string...you could use the innerHTML property as a way to append the img tag as a child of your div, but this is considered a security risk.

Another way to do it is creating multiple templates within ng-template tags, using the correct elements for your use case and choosing one of them to render dynamically, passing the current ngFor element as a context variable ([this article](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-ng-template-ng-container-ngtemplateoutlet/) can help you understand how to achieve this)!

Cheers!

Comment: I ended up doing something similar to your multiple templates route. My *ngFor is creating an element with an [ngSwitch] in it with the *switchCase options being a few different tags like <img> or <dummy-component>. and I am now using a context variable from "project.previewType" as the switch expression.

Comment: Great! I'm glad it worked! A good thing about this pattern is that it keeps the template fully understandable by itself...along with the security risk, the innerHTML usage makes the template harder to understand, since we have no idea what's gonna be appended there!